# Как установить libsamplerate для питона?

Tags: python

Как установить libsamplerate для питона?

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install libsamplerate
```

Comment: А в винде?

Comment: наверное так же. Но сначала надо установить pip.

Comment: а как установить pip?

Comment: Скачайте с http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip архив с исходниками, распакуйте, прочитайте файл docs/installing.txt